# NSSortDescriptor alternative in c++

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I am porting my game from Cocos2d to Cocos2dx. I have used the following code in a module

```
   enter code here
NSMutableArray * tempArray = roomModels;
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"displayOrder" ascending:YES];
[tempArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

Is there any solution to port this code into c++ using Cocos2dx?

Answer (score 0):

Cocos2d works on objC but CocoS2dX is designed to use c++ so it has its own collection objects, the objectiveC classes like NSMutableArray is replaced by the CCARRAY class.
Read the Official documentation of COCOS2Dx for further info .
check out here:
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Getting_Started